# Magento: can two modules extend the same core model?

Tags: php, oop, magento, overriding

Is it possible to create two modules which extend the same core model like `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer`?

What will I receive when I access the (overloaded) core model?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815717/multiple-modules-overriding-same-core-file-in-magento

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend the Model class across custom models:

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Customer1 extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
```

defined in app/code/local/Namespace/Customer/Model/Customer1.php, and:

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Customer2 extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
```

defined in app/code/local/Namespace/Customer/Model/Customer2.php.

that should be fine - You'll have to specify which model you want when you call it:

```
Mage::getModel('namespace/customer1')->method()
```

or

```
Mage::getModel('namespace/customer2')->method()
```

the core model will be unchanged:

```
Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
```

Comment: A quick note on language.  You're not extending modules.  You're extending **models**.  A **module** allows you to add your own code to the system.  A **model** is a regular PHP object instantiated from a class. A **module** can have many models.