# Multiple modules overriding same core file in Magento

Tags: magento

How does Magento handle multiple modules overriding the same core file?   Is it possible?  How is it done?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have 3 choices for resolving conflicts:

- Merge the code from one conflicting file into another and switch off the rewrite config.xml in one
- Switch off the rewrite in one config.xml and then make the conflicting extension PHP file extend the other extension
- Use the `<depends>` capability to make one extension depend on another. They will then rewrite in that order

Example (option # 2)

```
class A_Extension_Model_Type_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage
```

You would change it to:

```
class A_Extension_Model_Type_Onepage extends B_Extension_Model_Type_Onepage
```

Read more @ http://www.webshopapps.com/blog/2010/11/resolving-magento-extension-conflicts/

Comment: Thank you for the response.  These all seem to apply only if you control both modules.  A better way to restate my question would be:  How does Magento handle two modules by different developers that edit the same core file?  Is it up to the person downloading the modules to verify collisions like that?

Comment: That the only way, when you are buying/installing modules you have to make sure they are compatible with each other. Sometime you have to modify as needed