# Magento. Conflict of extensions

Tags: magento

I used 2 extensions which overwrite the same file:

```
1st: app/code/community/Symmetrics/DeliveryTime/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Grid.php
2nd:app/code/community/Displaze/MyProductType/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Grid.php
```

2nd extension doesn't work.
How I could resolve this conflict?
I use `magento 1.7`

Comment: Hey @Derk153 this is the developer of Displaze_MyProductType extension, since Magento put that extension offline for what ever reason, and I don't have the code since I my hard drive fried and I never put the code on git which I intended to, so can you please share the extension with me? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app/etc/Displaze_MyProductType.xml

add below code

<modules>
   <Displaze_MyProductType>
      <depends>
          <Symmetrics_DeliveryTime/>
      </depends>
   </Displaze_MyProductType>
 </modules>
```

Comment: or you van slao merge on in another and delte one file

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 choices for resolving conflicts:

- Merge the code from one conflicting file into another and switch off the rewrite config.xml in one
- Switch off the rewrite in one config.xml and then make the conflicting extension PHP file extend the other extension
- Use the `<depends>` capability to make one extension depend on another. They will then rewrite in that order

Example (option # 2)

```
class A_Extension_Model_Type_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage
```

You would change it to:

```
class A_Extension_Model_Type_Onepage extends B_Extension_Model_Type_Onepage
```

See [Multiple modules overriding same core file in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815717/multiple-modules-overriding-same-core-file-in-magento)