# How to customize two magento extensions to work together?

Tags: magento

I bought two magento extensions (let call them A and B). Each one do a specific task, but I would like them to work together to do exactly what I want.

Here is see four ways to do that:

1. Change the code of A to work with B
2. Change the code of B to work with A
3. Change the code of B and A to work together
4. Develop a extension C to do the bridge between A and B

The last one seems to be the best, but it's only theory, cause in practice we know that it's never that easy. The first and the second seem good since I only change one extension, but what if the one I changed is updated? My code gonna be overwritten, and I will have to merge the last version with the new one, and redo that process every time an new update shows up.

In fact, I'm kind of new in Magento, and I'm not sure where to start, and how to process. Did you guys have advice on what I should do, and what I should NOT do. Like in every business, I want to find an in between having perfect code, and spending too much time on that.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 choices for resolving conflicts:

- Merge the code from one conflicting file into another and switch off the rewrite config.xml in one
- Switch off the rewrite in one config.xml and then make the conflicting extension PHP file extend the other extension
- Use the `<depends>` capability to make one extension depend on another. They will then rewrite in that order

Example (option # 2)

```
class A_Extension_Model_Type_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage
```

You would change it to:

```
class A_Extension_Model_Type_Onepage extends B_Extension_Model_Type_Onepage
```

See [Multiple modules overriding same core file in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815717/multiple-modules-overriding-same-core-file-in-magento)